# Problem in identifying positive and negative terminals of a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, multimeter

I have a fan with a capacitor reported to be defective.

I need to test it with a multimeter. But there are no positive or negative markings for the terminals.

Here are a few pictures.

[image]
[image]
[image]

There's a marking at the bottom which could be a company logo.

[image]

How do I identify the positive and negative terminals?

Comment: Did you search for an eventual datasheet ?

Comment: It may just be unpolarized.

Comment: A capacitor from a fan is a motor-start capacitor and is not polarized. It doesn't have positive and negative terminals because it's used in an AC circuit, not DC. It's used to create a phase-shift in the motor's secondary windings to get it spinning.

Comment: @M.Ferru I didn't, as I do not know about these much, though I'm interested to learn. But I don't think I'll get a data sheet: the capacitor is old and the company is a local one. If you find one, please give the reference.

Comment: @brhans So, the multimeter probes can be put on any terminal?

Comment: @brhans Also, how do I ensure that the capacitor is discharged? I have a few 1k ohm resistors of 1/4 W, can they discharge this?

Comment: Going to bet you don't have a meter that can measure that much capacitance. Turn the power to the fan on and give it a spin manually. If it runs, let the electrician do his job.

Comment: @Matt I don't want to measure capacitance. I only want to see if it's dead or not. He said it's dead. The fan runs properly, and I don't want to do anything with it. I just want to see that if he told the truth that the capacitor is dead. Took quite a lot of money saying this.

Comment: It runs properly without the capacitor?

Comment: @Matt the electrician has already changed the capacitor.

Comment: I have the one which he says is "dead", and I want to give it the death certificate after post mortem ;-)

Comment: So the facts are these.  The fan did not work.  Electrician changes capacitor and it works.  The evidence sort of speaks for itself, doesn't it.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat The electrician not only changed capacitor but also bearings, and the coil inside. Anything happens to any fan, and he has to change the capacitor. This has happened multiple times. I think this time only the bearings were jammed, because the fan stopped **suddenly** when it was working smoothly. The electrician says that the coil was burnt, so why did he change the capacitor also?

Answer (score 1):

That capacitor is not polarized.  There is no positive and negative lead.  You can connect it either way.

Answer (score 1):

A motor start capacitor does not have a dedicated polarity.  It is not readily testable with a multimeter since a relevant part of it being ok is that it will behave sensibly under mains voltage.  That is so far above multimeter test voltages that you cannot really say a lot about it if the multimeter does not find fault with it.

In addition, if a fan coil is shot, that can very well be the fault of a motor start capacitor breakthrough.  Since motor coils are way more expensive than motor capacitors and way harder to change, it would be negligent to replace only the coil because that carries considerable risk of having to repeat the whole repair.

So even in case the capacitor happens to be perfectly fine after all (which is hard to verify), exchanging it in the course of this repair certainly was a good call to make.

With regard to discharging, I'd rather aim for a few hundreds of kiloohms and leave them on for an hour or so.  High voltage capacitors can really pack a punch.  And even after removing a discharge resistor, they can slowly relax into having voltage across them again.  So "but I definitely discharged it before I put it into storage" is not good enough if you want to avoid trouble.